# Qt cant load temporary status message

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, statusbar

I have a class

```
class Window: public QMainWindow {
    // ...

private:
    Ui::MainWindow ui; 
}
```

Where Ui::MainWindow is the auto generated **ui_mainwindow.h** for the **mainwindow.ui** form.
In my constructor

```
Window::Window(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    ui.retranslateUi(this);
    ui.statusbar->message(tr("Hello"), 3000); // here is the error
}
```

It says **message could not be resolved.**. So how can I set a temporary status here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ui.statusbar->`**showMessage**`(tr("Hello"), 3000); // here is the error`

Answer (score 1):

it's `void QStatusBar::showMessage ( const QString & message, int timeout = 0 )`. Not only `message`